# Not able to install modules p5-Expect, P5-IO-Tty, p5-IO-Stty, p5-Digest-MD5, p5-YAML in FreeBSD 10

Tags: software-installation, package-management, freebsd

I have installed OS FreeBSD 10.1 and installed perl 5.16 from my folder `/usr/ports/lang/perl5.16`.

then i did:

```
# portsnap fetch
# portsnap extract
```

then I am trying to `make install clean` port p5-IO-Expect from `cd /usr/ports/lang/p5-Expect` for which I get below error:

```
$ make install clean
===>  p5-Expect-1.32 depends on package: p5-IO-Tty>=1.11 - not found
===>  Verifying install for p5-IO-Tty>=1.11 in /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty
===>  Installing for p5-IO-Tty-1.12_1
===>  p5-IO-Tty-1.12_1 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/perl5.16.3 - found
===>  Checking if p5-IO-Tty already installed
===>  Switching to root credentials for 'install' target
Password:
===>  Registering installation for p5-IO-Tty-1.12_1 as automatic
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/man/man3/IO::Pty.3.gz: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/man/man3/IO::Tty.3.gz: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/man/man3/IO::Tty::Constant.3.gz: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/IO/Pty.pm: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/IO/Tty.pm: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/IO/Tty/Constant.pm: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/auto/IO/Tty/Tty.so: No such file or directory
*** Error code 74
Stop.
make[2]: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/lang/p5-Expect
```

And then when I try to install `p5-IO-Tty` from `/usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty` then I get below error

```
$ make install clean
===>  Installing for p5-IO-Tty-1.12_1
===>  p5-IO-Tty-1.12_1 depends on file: /usr/local/bin/perl5.16.3 - found
===>  Checking if p5-IO-Tty already installed
===>  Switching to root credentials for 'install' target
Password:
===>  Registering installation for p5-IO-Tty-1.12_1
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/man/man3/IO::Pty.3.gz: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/man/man3/IO::Tty.3.gz: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/man/man3/IO::Tty::Constant.3.gz: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/IO/Pty.pm: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/IO/Tty.pm: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/IO/Tty/Constant.pm: No such file or directory
pkg-static: Unable to access file /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty/work/stage/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/mach/5.16/auto/IO/Tty/Tty.so: No such file or directory
*** Error code 74
Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/ports/devel/p5-IO-Tty
```

please help me to resolve this issue...
    which are the exact versions to install for other modules also

Comment: Did you `make index` in `/usr/ports`?

Comment: Well i did make index in /usr/ports and also
portsnap fetch update
make -C /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster install clean
portmaster -aftd But still I am stuck with same issue, perl modules are not installing
I am basically preparing IPv6 conformance testing using TAHI framework
I also have KDE as desktop environment installed

Comment: @Namrata are you the original poster of this question? If so, please [merge](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You have an outdated environment. And I'm pretty sure you never look at `/usr/ports/UPDATING`

do the full update of the installed software:

```
portsnap fetch update
make -C /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster install clean
portmaster -aftd
```

This may take a while.